# Why is my loss function always returning nan?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to learn about ML and I tried to make a simple linear model, but when I run it, loss comes out as null:

[image: Terminal output]

So I tried to find whats the problem about. If I print first 10 y_pred, only about 17 of them have numbers, the rest of them are null. Maybe im doing something wrong, please help.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

#Input (temp, rainfall, humidity)
inputs = np.array([[73, 67, 43], [91, 88, 64], [87, 134, 58], [102, 43, 37], [69, 96, 70], [73, 67, 43], [91, 88, 64], [87, 134, 58], [102, 43, 37], [69, 96, 70], [73, 67, 43], [91, 88, 64], [87, 134, 58], [102, 43, 37], [69, 96, 70]], dtype='float32')

#Target (apples, oranges)
targets = np.array([[56, 70], [81, 101], [119, 133], [22, 37], [103, 119], [56, 70], [81, 101], [119, 133], [22, 37], [103, 119], [56, 70], [81, 101], [119, 133], [22, 37], [103, 119]], dtype='float32')

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)

#Define datasets
train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)
train_ds[0:3]

#Hyperparameters
batch_size = 5
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.01

train_dl = DataLoader(dataset=train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


model = nn.Linear(3,2) #inputs(temp, rainfall, humidity) , targets(apples, oranges)

loss_f = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for xb, yb in train_dl:
        y_pred = model(xb)
        loss = loss_f(y_pred, yb)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
    if(epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'epoch = {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, loss = {loss.item():.4f}')
        
print(f'Final loss = {loss.item():.4f}')
```

edit:
`y_pred.shape = torch.Size([5, 2]), yb.shape = torch.Size([5, 2])`

Comment: First, please check the shape of y_pred and yb. Can you show us these shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about the Loss function. Your model is predicting `Nan` and `Infy` numbers. Possible solution

- Reduce the learning rate (Ex.:`learning_rate = 0.001`) or
- Reduce batch size (Ex.: `batch_size = 2`) or
- Add more layers into the model with activation functions or
- Normalize inputs

Comment: It was the learning rate. I understand why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the given amount of information, my first attempt would be changing

```
loss_f = nn.MSELoss()
```

to

```
loss_f = nn.MSELoss(size_average=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still return nan. I will gladly provide more information if needed. I am new to all this so if you could please just tell me anything you need.